# COM event notification

Tags: c++, com

Without:

- ATL
- MFC

**Note:**

- Client is executing in a **different** thread to that of the server

**Question:**

- How do I **control** the **behaviour** of the client, once an **event notification** is received from the **COM object** (Server)?
- How to implement an event interface from client?

Illustration below:

```
hresult = pis8->QueryInterface(
                __uuidof(IConnectionPointContainer),
            (void **) &pContainer);

//result handling omitted


hresult = pContainer->FindConnectionPoint(
                      __uuidof(IS8SimulationEvents),
                      &pConnection);

//result handling omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client implements the event interface (`IS8SimulationEvents`) This can be in a separate component, or on the client component itself. The implementation is called when the component fires an event.

After `FindConnectionPoint`, the client calls `pConnection->Advise`, passing the `IS8SimulationEvents` and receiving a "cookie". The cookie is required to call `Unadvise`, which must be called during cleanup to disconnect.

If the client runs in a different thread than server, the client needs to run a message loop to receive calls.

Comment: How to implement a message loop efficiently?

Comment: see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows

YOu can quit this by PostQuitMessage, or adding another mechanism to the loop. If you need to mix message handling with waiting for events/similar things, use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects/Ex in the loop

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question right, seems like the client needs to be running a waitloop, something like

```
while(!threadCancel)
{
    DWORD waitResult = WaitForMultipleObjects(actionCount, waitHandles, FALSE, 500);
    switch (waitResult)
    {
        case SERVER_COMMAND_1:
            HandleServerCommand1();
            break;
        ...etc...
        default:
           throw ...
     }
}
```

The client's event sinks trigger the wait handles, effectively allowing the server to tell the client what to do.